# Copy range of cell values if the sheet name is equal to cell value in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy the values in column C if the sheetname is equal to the cell value in column A
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHjw9.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kplx.png)

I used

DataWSheet.Range("C2", DataWSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("D4")

but it gave me all the cell values in the main sheet.

Here is the complete code that I used

```
Sub CreateBranchSheets()

Dim BranchField As Range
Dim BranchName As Range
Dim NewWSheet As Worksheet
Dim WSheet As Worksheet
Dim WSheetFound As Boolean
Dim DataWSheet As Worksheet

Set DataWSheet = Worksheets("Loans")
Set BranchField = DataWSheet.Range("A2", DataWSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop through each branch name in column A

For Each BranchName In BranchField

'Check whether the current branch name corresponds with an existing sheet name

    For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WSheet.Name = BranchName Then
            WSheetFound = True
                    Exit For ' if it does assign True to the WSheetFound variable and exit the For Each Next Loop
        Else
            WSheetFound = False ' if it doesn't assign False to the WSheetFound variable
        End If
    Next WSheet
    
    
    If WSheetFound Then 'if WSheetFound = True
    
   
    
    
        
        Else 'if WSheetFound = False
        
        Set NewWSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) ' insert a new Worksheet
        NewWSheet.Name = BranchName 'named after that branch
        
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "H"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Account Name"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Amount"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Bill Date"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Comment"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Pay Method"
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Post Date"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "D"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Detail Amount"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Detail Comment"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Unit"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Job"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "GLAccount ID"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Property Short Name"
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "H"
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "21st Mortgage Corporation"
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R3C7,Loans!C1:C12,11,0)+VLOOKUP(R3C7,Loans!C1:c12,12,0)"
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Enter Invoice Date"
    Range("G3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveSheet.Name
    Range("H3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ACH"
    Range("I3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    DataWSheet.Range("C2", DataWSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("D4")
    
  
    End If

Next BranchName

'autofit columns in each sheet in the workbook

For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    WSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

Next WSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from your data and edit it into your question.